# Hbase distributed scan issue using Spark2

Tags: apache-spark, nosql, hbase

When i am trying to execute hbase operation programmatically from  spark/scala file

**Observation** 
We just migrated from spark 1.6 version to 2.3 version and hbase 1.2 version same in both the cases. but now we are facing the issue while doing hbase distributed scan operation

**Getting Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: /0.0.0.0:60020 is unable to read call parameter from client ; java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GetRegionLoad
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.instantiateException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.makeIOExceptionOfException(ProtobufUtil.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getRegionMetrics(HBaseAdmin.java:2129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RegionSizeCalculator.init(RegionSizeCalculator.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RegionSizeCalculator.<init>(RegionSizeCalculator.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.oneInputSplitPerRegion(TableInputFormatBase.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.getSplits(TableInputFormat.java:254)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1162)
    at com.amobee.spark.dps.cdp.util.CopyHbaseTableUtil$.main(CopyHbaseTableUtil.scala:53)
    at com.amobee.spark.dps.cdp.util.CopyHbaseTableUtil.main(CopyHbaseTableUtil.scala)
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this operation is incompatible with HBase below 2.x

Comment: Do we need to upgrade hbase >2.x

Comment: I got this functionality to work under HBase 2.0, but I ended up not using it, because I noticed that there are too many round-trip connections being made to HBase, which seemed too expensive for me time-wise.

Comment: Yes, but just as a word of caution, some of your other sub-2.0 client API might break under 2.0 as well, if I remember correctly. It's nothing major, but some stuff related to table creation, etc. if I remember correctly. So you may have to do some work on that as well to bring it up to the 2.0 client API.